# how to fetch commented name on posts in laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, eloquent, comments, posts

i followed the convention to avail the required data with compact method to view
Schema User Table

```
id,name,email,password
```

Schema post Table

```
id,user_id,title,body,photo
```

Schema comment Table

```
id,post_id,user_id,comments,photo
```

in user model

```
public function post()
  {
      return $this->hasMany(post::class);
  }

 public function comments()
   {
     return $this->hasMany(comment::class);
   }
```

in post model

```
Public function User()
{
  return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}

public function comments()
{
    return $this->hasMany(comment::class);

}
```

in comment model

```
public function posts()
{
 return $this->belongsTo('App\post');
}
```

in controller

```
$list = User::with('post','comments')->paginate(1);

  return view('dynamic',compact('list'));
```

in view

```
@foreach($lists->comments as $comments)
{{$comments->name}}
@endforeach
```

post showing successfully according to users

and comments showing successfully according to posts

but commented name not showing up // please help

how to make relationship for fetch comments with commented user name

please help thanks in advance

Comment: please help
i am trying to 2 days

Comment: try this `$list = User::with('post.comments')->paginate(1);`

Comment: always use singular function name for `belongsTo` relation and plural function name for `hasMany`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to change your code as below

```
@foreach($lists->comments as $comments)
    {{$comments->posts->user->name}}
@endforeach
```

or

you need to add relationship to your comment model as below

```
  Public function User()
{
  return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

after that you need to change your code as below

```
@foreach($lists->comments as $comments)
    {{$comments->user->name}}
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

change code as below in your view:

```
@foreach($lists->comments as $comments)
    {{$comments->User->name}}
@endforeach
```